# How to define homomorphisms of rings on $\mathbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was studying some examples of ring homomorphisms. The common solution for defining homomorphism $\phi$ from the ring of Gauss integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is to define it only on $i$ and it is always sufficient for this condition $\phi(i)^2=-1$ to be true for the homomorphism to be well-defined. I can't understand why it is enough to define $\phi$ only on $i$? I think it has something to do with the following isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, but I can't explain it strictly mathematical. And if I have an arbitary ring $R$, how do I decide on which elements to define homomorphism?

Comment: That's because $\phi(1)=1$ for any ring homomorphism. Then for any $a+b i  \in  \mathbb Z[i]$, $\phi(a+bi) = \phi(a 1 + bi) = a \phi(1)+b\phi(i)= a+b\phi(i)$. Therefore, by defining $\phi(i)$, $\phi$ is completely defined. Moreover $\phi(i)^2=\phi(i^2)=\phi(-1)=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i]$ given by $f+(x^2+1)\to f(i)$ for $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So the element $i$ is identified via this isomorphism with the coset $x+(x^2+1)$.

Now, given a commutative ring $R$, and an element $r\in R$, we may define a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to R$ by $\phi(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ix^i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_ir^i$. Note that $a_i$ on the right hand side means $a_i\cdot 1_R$, summing the identity $a_i$ times. If $\phi(x)=r$ satisfies $r^2=-1$ then $x^2+1\in Ker(\phi)$, and so the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is contained in the kernel of $\phi$. In this case, $\phi$ induces a well defined homomorphism on the quotient ring:

$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\to R$

by $f+(x^2+1)\to\phi(f)$. This is the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\to R$ we were looking for.

Of course, you could check that the map is well defined directly by using the standard definition of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, without using the isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$. However, such presentations as quotients are also used in more general cases, so it's good to see how this works. For the homomorphism to be well defined, what you basically need is to preserve the "relations" of the ring. Formally, this means that the elements of the ideal by which you divide (here it was $(x^2+1)$) have to be mapped to $0$.